# Pass special characters from django to views.py

Tags: python, regex, special-characters, django-urls

I am trying to pass a string from an Html page to views.py

The string has some special characters, string:

```
Clarithromycin 500 MG Extended Release Tablet;http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/;259543;9/4/2010;2;d;1 bid;Prescription;http://smartplatforms.org/terms/codes/MedicationProvenance#;prescription ;1;{tablet} ;7/7/2014;2007-10-03 03:00:00+03;
```

I have found that the problem is in urls.py in regex expression. The string is not passed after special character '#'

urls.py :

```
   (r'^bulkimport/importMedications/(?P<stringP>.+)', importMedications),
```

I have also tried

```
  (r'^bulkimport/importMedications/(?P<stringP>[\w\+%_&\# ].+)', importMedications),
```

and the passed string is:

```
Clarithromycin 500 MG Extended Release Tablet;http:/purl.bioontology.org/ontology/RXNORM/;259543;9/4/2010;2;d;1 bid;Prescription;http:/smartplatforms.org/terms/codes/MedicationProvenance
```

If I remove character '#' all the string is passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hash mark `#` is a reserved character in URLs, it introduces the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

To use it in a URL, you have to [percent escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it as `%23`. You can use [urllib.quote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) to do that.

However, I would strongly advise you to use POST requests to import your data, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with GET. I could not pass '+' character. I did following:

```
q_string = dict(x.split('=')
    for x in request.META['QUERY_STRING'].split('&')
)
```

And then I used q_string instead request.GET.